# what is GUI and non GUI difference in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

what are the two types of execution that can be done in jmeter?
This was asked in a interview to me. i was asked what are the ways u execute the script i.e GUI or non -GUI. I  am working on jmeter but I have never come across these two words

Answer (score 2):

GUI means "graphical user interface", like you run in microsoft windows.

We can run Jmeter in both GUI or Non-GUI (From command line).

I strongly suggest you do some reading about Jmeter on below website
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html

http://developer.amd.com/community/blog/2009/03/31/using-apache-jmeter-in-non-gui-mode/

hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely [not recommended](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) to use JMeter GUI (graphical user interface) for anything apart from developing or debugging test as AWT Event Thread will kill both your test and JMeter in case of more or less high load.

There is a variety of approaches on how to run a JMeter test in non-GUI mode including:

- command-line mode
- Apache Ant task
- Apache Maven plugin
- Jenkins plugin
- Execution pre-defined .jmx from Java code or creating a test on-the-fly
- Plugins for IDEs like Eclipse or Idea

See [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) for more details on above.